# Code to find Endianness-pointer typecasting

Tags: c++, c, endianness

I was trying to search for a code to determine the endianness of the system, and this is what I found:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int i= 1;
    char *c = (char *)&i;
    if (*c) {
        printf("Little Endian\n");
    } else {
        printf("Big Endian\n");
    }
}
```

Could someone tell me how this code works? More specifically, why is the ampersand needed here in this typecasting :

```
char *c = (char *)&i;
```

What is getting stored into the pointer c.. the value i contains or the actual address i is contained in? Also why is this a char for this program?

Comment: uuhhh, this doesn't work. However, it would work if `i` was assigned to 1 I think...

Comment: @Dave I'm a bit skeptical too, but then again I don't really understand some of the black magic people think of.

Comment: Endian, not Indian

Comment: The idea seems to be to look at the lowest-memory address of `i`, and test if it's non-zero (apparently implying little endian else big ~). For that to work, `i` must be known to have non-zero content in the least signficant bits, but 0s in the most significant bits. Loading `i` with any number between 1 and 2^(sizeof(int)-1)*8-1 would satisfy that condition, but 1 or 255 are the obvious numbers to use.

Comment: The ampersand is to get the address of i (which is normally 4 bytes). It is then cast it into a char pointer (which is 1 byte)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While dereferencing a character pointer, only one byte is interpreted(Assuming a `char` variable takes one byte).And in `little-endian` mode,the `least-significant-byte` of an integer is stored first.So for a 4-byte integer,say 3,it is stored as

```
00000011 00000000  00000000  00000000
```

while for `big-endian` mode it is stored as:

```
00000000  00000000  00000000  00000011
```

So in the first case, the `char*`  interprets the first byte and displays `3` but in the second case it displays `0`.

Had you not typecasted it as :

```
char *c = (char *)&i;
```

it will show a warning about incompatible pointer type.Had `c` been an `integer pointer`, dereferencing it will get an integer value `3` irrespective of the endianness,as all 4 bytes will be interpreted.

**NB** You need to initialize the variable `i` to see the whole picture.Else a garbage value is stored in the variable by default.

**Warning!!** OP,we discussed the difference between `little-endian` and `big-endian`,but it's more important to know the difference between `little-endian` and `little-indian`.I noticed that you used the latter.Well, the difference is that `little-indian` can cost you your dream job in Google or a $3 million in venture capital if your interviewer is a `Nikesh Arora,Sundar Pichai,Vinod Dham or Vinod Khosla` :-)

Comment: My bad, I copied it from a site, and didn't look through it all that carefully.. I was more interested in the type casting than in what was written in the printf. Will correct it no though, thanks!!

Comment: @Floose Hey,I was only kidding.That's only an innocent spelling mistake and doesn't mean that much to the program!!

Answer (score 4):

Let's try to walk through this: (in comments)

```
int main(void){ /
  unsigned int i = 1;    // i is an int in memory that can be conceptualized as 
                         // int[0x00 00 00 01]

  char *c = *(char *)&i; // We take the address of i and then cast it to a char pointer
                         // which we then dereference. This cast from int(4 bytes) 
                         // to char(1 byte) results in only keeping the lowest byte by
  if(*c){                // Endian-ness. 
    puts("little!\n");   // This means that on a Little Endian machine, 0x01 will be 
  } else {               // the byte kept, but on a Big Endian machine, 0x00 is kept.
    puts("big!\n");      // int[0x00 00 00 (char)[01]]  vs  int[0x01 00 00 (char)[00]]
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for replying.. Unfortunately, I could mark only one answer as correct, so here's me thanking you for your help. I'm clear now. Gave you an upvote :)

Comment: The description isn't accurate - there is no "downcasting" (that term means something very specific; please don't overload it like this). The `&i` notation takes the address of the variable `i`: i.e. it gives you a pointer to `unsigned int`. You then take that pointer and cast it to a pointer to `char`. The `*c` in the `if` then *dereferences* that character pointer, returning either the LSB or the MSB of the integer depending on the endianess of the platform the code is running on.

Comment: My apologies @Nik Bougalis, I revised my answer.